# jQuery toggle with gsap animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, gsap

i want to toggle a div that add the height from 10px to 200px.. my problem is if i click again it will animate back from 200px to 10px. and i dont know what to do.

heres my code.

the css

```
.container2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px;
}
.container .box {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: blue;
  display: none;
}
```

the html

```
<div class="container2">
    <div class="box bounceIn"></div>
</div>
```

the javascript

```
var con = $('.container2');
var box = $('.box');
var click = $('.click');

click.click( function() {
   TweenMax.to(con, 1, {height: '200px', ease:Bounce.easeOut});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This code will toggle back and forth between the two states.

```
var clicked = false;
click.click(function() {

   if(clicked){
        TweenMax.to(con, 1, {height: '10', ease:Bounce.easeOut});
   }else{
        TweenMax.to(con, 1, {height: '200', ease:Bounce.easeOut});
   }
   clicked = !clicked;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var clicked = false;

click.click( function() {

   if(clicked == false){
        TweenMax.to(con, 1, {height: '200px', ease:Bounce.easeOut});
   }else{
        TweenMax.to(con, 1, {height: '10px', ease:Bounce.easeOut});
   }

});
```